# need to add authentication header to azure devops api request

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to get information on my latest builds by sending a GET request to the Azure DevOps REST Api. I'm using Azure DevOps Server 2020 with the Patch 1 update. I need to add an authorization header to the request. The header I added is not working.

I'm doing the request in Powershell. Here's my code:

```
$PAT = 'personal access token'
$ENCODED = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($PAT))

$headers = @{
Authorization="Basic $ENCODED"
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri [azure devops server url]/[project name]/_apis/build/latest/Build?api-version=5.0 -Method Get -Headers $headers
```

When I run the code I get the error: `Invoke Method: The format of value [PAT] is invalid`

UPDATE:
I updated the header syntax. Now the reponse I get:

```
Invoke-RestMethod:

        TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required. - Azure DevOps Server
```

I also tried passing my Azure DevOps username and password in the header like this:

```
$headers = @{
  Authorization="Basic [domain\username]:[password]"
}
```

and I got this in response:

```
Invoke-RestMethod: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

Do I have to enable some setting in Azure DevOps?

Comment: Try `$headers = @{Authorization="Basic $ENCODED"}` instead.

Comment: I changed the header syntax. Now I get `Invoke-RestMethod:

        TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required. - Azure DevOps Server`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually reference to this demo to run REST API in PowerShell, it can work fine:

```
$uri = "request URI"

$pat = "personal access token"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo))
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
. . .

$body = "{
           . . .
         }"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $body -Method POST
```

In your case, the issue seems is caused by the encoding. Try using **`ASCII`** or **`UTF8`**, instead of **`Unicode`**.

To view more details, you can see "[**Use personal access tokens**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#use-a-pat)".

Comment: It was a token encoding issue. Your solution worked. Thanks.